# Maximization of non-convex function over a convex set.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have ${n\choose 2}$ non negative variables $0\leq v_{ij}\leq \frac{1}{2}$, $1\leq i<j\leq n$, and I'm trying to solve the maximization
$$ \max_{v_{ij}}\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}|S|=r\\ S\subseteq [n]\end{subarray}}\prod_{i<j\in S}(\frac{1}{2}+v_{ij})\\s.t\;\; \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}v_{ij}=c\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0\leq v_{ij}\leq \frac{1}{2}$$
I was able to show that $$v_{ij}=\frac{c}{{n\choose 2}}$$ is a local maximum, and I wonder if I can prove that it is a global one as well?
I'll appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Do you need to prove that $v_{ij}=\frac{c}{\binom{n}{2}}$ is a global maximum? What do you know about this topic (definitions, theorems, etc) what have you seen?

Comment: Yes, I guess (when by global I mean over the feasible set derived from the constraints)

Comment: I am not very familiar with the topic, I had the basic "convex optimization" course, and read a bit about systems of polynomial equations. Will be happy to get pointers.

Comment: Looks like you have ignored the condition $|S|=r$.

Comment: How come? This is not a constraint, its just part of the definition of the objective, but I get that this is a local maximum for any $r$.